# How to implement document viewer UI in webpage i.e open a pdf file?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design

I have UI which shows an applicant's picture on the left and applicant's information on the right and also an option to open the applicant's resume

[image]

when I click "Open resume" button this what it looks like

[image]

How can I display user resume in a better way with user-friendliness? In other words, how would you do it differently?

Comment: Can you please explain what you need help with specifically or what the answer you are looking for is? Design solutions are dependent on a number of variables, and user friendliness is subject to the needs of the specific user/user groups. By providing some ideas on what you want to achieve with the design it will help us to answer the question better.

Comment: @MichaelLai what i wanted to know is what is the better of opening the resume. how would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **opening the resume in a modal popup**, similar to the Mac application 'Preview' (see image below).

[image: mac preview]

Then the user can preview the content of the document, and decide what action to take from there.

If they decide to open it, I would suggest to open it in a different tab, so that the user does not lose their current page in your application.

Comment: good answer, though consider the long term usage of this piece of knowledge. I edited to remove informal/personal language ("if I were you")  as these answers should be considered to be more than just a specific response to one person. Think about it more as creating reference material for many people over time, rather than responding to an individual.